# Why did I get an error with my XmlSerializer?

Tags: wpf, system.xml

I made a couple of changes to my working application and started getting the following error at this line of code.

```
Dim Deserializer As New Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Groups))
```

And here is the error.

```
    BindingFailure was detected
    Message: The assembly with display name 'FUSE.XmlSerializers' failed to load in the 'LoadFrom' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FUSE.XmlSerializers, Version=8.11.16.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'FUSE.XmlSerializers, Version=8.11.16.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

    Message: The assembly with display name 'FUSE.XmlSerializers' failed to load in the 'LoadFrom' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FUSE.XmlSerializers, Version=8.11.16.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'FUSE.XmlSerializers, Version=8.11.16.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = DOUG-VM\Doug
LOG: DisplayName = FUSE.XmlSerializers, Version=8.11.16.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, processorArchitecture=MSIL
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///E:/Laptop/Core Data/Data/Programming/Windows/DotNet/Work Projects/NOP/Official Apps/FUSE WPF/Fuse/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: E:\Laptop\Core Data\Data\Programming\Windows\DotNet\Work Projects\NOP\Official Apps\FUSE WPF\Fuse\bin\Debug\FUSE.vshost.exe.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/Laptop/Core Data/Data/Programming/Windows/DotNet/Work Projects/NOP/Official Apps/FUSE WPF/Fuse/bin/Debug/FUSE.XmlSerializers.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/Laptop/Core Data/Data/Programming/Windows/DotNet/Work Projects/NOP/Official Apps/FUSE WPF/Fuse/bin/Debug/FUSE.XmlSerializers/FUSE.XmlSerializers.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/Laptop/Core Data/Data/Programming/Windows/DotNet/Work Projects/NOP/Official Apps/FUSE WPF/Fuse/bin/Debug/FUSE.XmlSerializers.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/Laptop/Core Data/Data/Programming/Windows/DotNet/Work Projects/NOP/Official Apps/FUSE WPF/Fuse/bin/Debug/FUSE.XmlSerializers/FUSE.XmlSerializers.EXE.
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The main reason this was happening was because I had a mismatch in the types I was trying to Serialize and Deserialize. I was Serializing ObservableCollection (of Group) and deserializing a business object - Groups which inherited ObservableCollection (of Group).

And this was also part of the problem...
From - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/9f0c169f-c45e-4898-b2c4-f72c816d4b55/

> This exception is a part of the
>   XmlSerializer's normal operation. It
>   is expected and will be caught and
>   handled inside of the Framework code.
>   Just ignore it and continue. If it
>   bothers you during debugging, set the
>   Visual Studio debugger to only stop on
>   unhandled exceptions instead of all
>   exceptions.

Comment: Thank you very much, i was playing around with my Debug/Exceptions and forgot. Thanks alot.

Comment: One of the possible ways to get rid of this problem is check "Just my code" option in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General options.

Comment: Another (VS2010): Debug -> Exceptions; Managed Debugging Assistance -> BindingFailure -> uncheck "Thrown".

Comment: @Irwin just lost 2 hours of my life because of this too ><

Answer (score 8):

According to information I found, BindingFailure exception associated with XmlSerializers sometimes does not indicate any error and should be just ignored, but you can sometimes see it i. e. in debug mode, when you have set VS options to show all thrown exceptions.

Source:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=88566&wa=wsignin1.0

Btw. this is more or less one of the things mentioned in the first answer :).

Comment: Adding additional answers is not a problem, IMO.

Comment: I've written the answer more precisely, because people kept asking about this issue. I wrote it so the solution would be more visible, although the solution can be different in some cases.

Comment: This is what fixed it for me.  Left the office Friday afternoon with VS set to show all thrown exceptions and couldn't figure out on Monday why I was getting exceptions thrown in one part of the solution and not the other!

Comment: Smacks to me of someone using misusing exceptions to handle predicatable control flow - there's a code smell there, just in Microsoft's code.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you cannot locate the assembly FUSE.XmlSerializers. Check the results of the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Fuslogvw.exe) to see where it is looking (although the list presented above seems pretty full).

Try to locate where this assembly is stored on your computer and run [NGen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Image_Generator) on it to see if it is failing to load for some reason. Make sure this DLL file is appearing in your *Bin\Debug* directory. Visual Studio doesn't seem to get the dependencies of dependencies, and so you have to make sure you have all the files you need yourself sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

How did you load the assembly containing the `Groups` type? I'm guessing you loaded it with `Assembly.LoadFrom()` because the XML serializer is using the same context (the 'LoadFrom' context) to attempt to load assemblies for serialization. If so, you have a couple of options:

1. Use `Assembly.Load()` instead of `Assembly.LoadFrom()`.
2. Attach a handler to `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` to help the CLR find the assembly in question.

Answer (score 0):

For the select few Visual Studio projects I have where this is an annoyance, I prefer to disable break on exception for just the **BindingFailure** and the **System.IO.FileNotFoundException**.

In Visual Studio: <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for the Exceptions dialog:

1) Uncheck BindingFailure under **Managed Debugging Assistants**

2) Uncheck System.IO.FileNotFoundException  under **Common Language Runtime Exceptions**.

Ahhh that’s better :-)

...and I see 1/2 this answer was given by strager Nov 24 '10 at 10:12