# Exception when saving List<string> to Settings

Tags: c#

I am trying to save List to settings using the following code. 
I have other controls bound to settings and they work fine, if I comment the first three lines then it seems to work OK, but otherwise I get exception on the save() method

```
StringCollection playLists = new StringCollection();
playLists.AddRange(getListsToSync().ToArray());
Properties.Settings.Default.PlayLists = playLists;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); //exception here..
```

I get this exception

Could not load file or assembly 'System.XmlSerializers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: What type did you specify for Default.PlayLists ?

Comment: System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection

Comment: Do you have System.XmlSerializers library in references of your project? If you have it, what is the version of .Net and what are the versions of the system libraries?

Comment: I am using .Net framework 3.5 there is no System.XmlSerializers reference in my project. Infact there is no such assembly name available to refer..

Comment: possible duplicate of [FileNotFoundException in ApplicationSettingsBase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494886/filenotfoundexception-in-applicationsettingsbase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accodring to [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/9f0c169f-c45e-4898-b2c4-f72c816d4b55/) you can just ignore the exception and your code should run fine.

From the link:

> This exception is a part of the XmlSerializer's normal operation. It is expected and will be caught and handled inside of the Framework code. Just ignore it and continue. If it bothers you during debugging, set the Visual Studio debugger to only stop on unhandled exceptions instead of all exceptions.