# exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location

Tags: c#, exception

I enable all exceptions, and get this weird exception:

> First-chance exception at 0x773ac41f in MyApp.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0038c23c..

the issue in "System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));"

```
public T GetObjectFromFile(string fileFullPath)
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileFullPath) == false)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileFullPath);

    try
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)reader.Deserialize(file);
    }
    catch
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    finally
    {
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is entirely normal, the reference answer [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3798614/17034).

Comment: This is not normal, this is sad! If you are using XmlSerializers than debugging should be painful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileNotFoundException in ApplicationSettingsBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494886/filenotfoundexception-in-applicationsettingsbase)