# Weird Exception Creating new XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, fileloadexception

I am instantiating an XmlSerializer for a custom class.  The line of code is pretty simple:

```
mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myClass));
```

I recently turned on the options to "Break When Thrown" for all "C++ Exceptions" in the Exception Settings window in Visual Studio 2017, and now get several exceptions when executing this line.  I can also see in the Output window, that this line throws 6 consecutive exceptions:

```
Exception thrown at 0x7565C5AF in myWinFormsApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x003BC7BC.
Exception thrown at 0x7565C5AF in myWinFormsApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x7565C5AF in myWinFormsApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x7565C5AF in myWinFormsApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x003BC6DC.
Exception thrown at 0x7565C5AF in myWinFormsApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x7565C5AF in myWinFormsApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
```

What's weird is that these exceptions are NOT caught by the try...catch block, do not interrupt the program execution flow, and the subsequent code correctly serializes and deserializes myClass.

The only unusual thing I can think of is that I instantiate the XmlSerializer in a .NET Framework 4.6.1 project, and "myClass" is defined in a .NET Standard 2.0 project.

What could be causing this?  Is it something I should be worried about when I move the code to a 24/7 Production environment?  Thanks!

Comment: [exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19386838) has a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386838/exception-eefileloadexception-at-memory-location#comment28732723_19386838) pointing to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494886/filenotfoundexception-in-applicationsettingsbase/3798614#3798614) to [FileNotFoundException in ApplicationSettingsBase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3494886/3744182).  See also [Exceptions raised running COM DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41524923).

Comment: The basic gist of those questions is that this isn't a problem, internally the `XmlSerializer` constructor might intentionally throw and catch a few first-chance exceptions as part of its algorithm.