# MyAssembly.XmlSerializers.dll not generated

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xmlserializer, sgen

I am using WCF Test Client to make a request to a service, however i get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'aDoc_Client.XmlSerializers' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IDWS_WS.AuthenticateUser(String user, String password)
   at DWS_WSClient.AuthenticateUser(String user, String password)
```

[image: WCF Test Client Exception]
I verified that i have Generate Serialization Assembly ON in the Project Properties -> Build.

I also activated SGEN to force the XML serialization, using this code([Generating an Xml Serialization assembly as part of my build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134224/generating-an-xml-serialization-assembly-as-part-of-my-build)) in the .csproj:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" 
        DependsOnTargets="AssignTargetPaths;Compile;ResolveKeySource" 
        Inputs="$(MSBuildAllProjects);@(IntermediateAssembly)" 
        Outputs="$(OutputPath)$(_SGenDllName)">
<!-- Delete the file because I can't figure out how to force the SGen task. -->
<Delete Files="$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).XmlSerializers.dll" ContinueOnError="true" />
  <SGen BuildAssemblyName="$(TargetFileName)" 
      BuildAssemblyPath="$(OutputPath)" 
      References="@(ReferencePath)" 
      ShouldGenerateSerializer="true" 
      UseProxyTypes="false" 
      KeyContainer="$(KeyContainerName)" 
      KeyFile="$(KeyOriginatorFile)" 
      DelaySign="$(DelaySign)" 
      ToolPath="$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)" 
      Platform="$(Platform)">
    <Output TaskParameter="SerializationAssembly" 
          ItemName="SerializationAssembly" />
  </SGen>
</Target>
```

however i get the following error:

```
There was an error reflecting type 'aDoc_Client.DocumentManagementExplicitService.OTAuthentication'.
```

[image: Reflecting type Exception]
I suspect this may be the cause of the first error, however this object is an object inside a Service Reference.

The Object declaration in Reference.cs is the following:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1015")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:api.ecm.opentext.com")]
public partial class OTAuthentication : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
    
    private string authenticationTokenField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string AuthenticationToken {
        get {
            return this.authenticationTokenField;
        }
        set {
            this.authenticationTokenField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("AuthenticationToken");
        }
    }
    
    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

How can i generate MyAssembly.XmlSerializers.dll?

**UPDATE 1:**

After inserting a try catch in the last point of contact between my application and the service reference:

```
public string AuthenticateUser(string userName, string userPassword) {
    string output = string.Empty;

    try
       {
           output = base.Channel.AuthenticateUser(userName, userPassword);
       }
    catch(Exception ex)
       {
           output = ex.ToString();
       }

    return output;
}
```

After returning a string with the exception, i get the following errors:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'aDoc_Client.XmlSerializers' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'aDoc_Client.XmlSerializers'

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean f or Int rospection,  Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.LoadWithPartialNameInternal(AssemblyName an, Evidence securityEvidence, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.Win32.Fusion.ReadCache(ArrayList alAssems, String name, UInt32 nFlag)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.EnumerateCache(AssemblyName partialName)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.LoadWithPartialNameInternal(AssemblyName an, Evidence securityEvidence, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadWithPartialName(String partialName, Evidence securityEvidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.LoadGeneratedAssembly(Type type, String defaultNamespace, XmlSerializerImplementation&amp; contract)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.SerializerGenerationContext.GenerateSerializers()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.SerializerGenerationContext.GetSerializer(Int32 handle)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean isReq uest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
   
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
   at aDoc_Client.AuthenticationExplicitService.Authentication.AuthenticateUser(String userName, String userPassword)
   at aDoc_Client.AuthenticationExplicitService.AuthenticationClient.AuthenticateUser(String userName, String userPassword)
   
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

**UPDATE 2:**

After running SGEN tool manually as specified in [Could not load MyAssembly.XmlSerializers.dll. The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465441/could-not-load-myassembly-xmlserializers-dll-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-sp) with visual studio command prompt i get the following errors:

```
Error: There was an error reflecting type
          'aDoc_Client.DocumentManagementExplicitService.OTAuthentication'.
  - Types 'aDoc_Client.DocumentManagementExplicitService.OTAuthentication' 
      and 'aDoc_Client.AuthenticationExplicitService.OTAuthentication' 
both use the XML type name, 'OTAuthentication', from namespace 'urn:api.ecm.opentext.com'. 
Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.

If you would like more help, please type "sgen /?".
```

aDoc_Client.DocumentManagementExplicitService and aDoc_Client.AuthenticationExplicitService are service references, it appears i need to find a way to specify new namespaces for the service references.

**UPDATE 3:**

As crazy as it seems, without changing a single line of code, there is a case where i don't get an exception when calling the service.

1. IIS Reset
2. Make a call to the service using WCF Test Client (FAILS)
3. Make a call to the service using WCF Test Client (FAILS)
4. Make a call to the service using a .net application (OK)
5. Make a call to the service using WCF Test Client (OK)

And this repeats forever, i cant seem to understand why it only works after being first called from a .net application.

Comment: What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback, and inner exception?  Likely the problem is explained in more detail there.

Comment: @dbc the post was updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the WCF Test Client Version.