# Could not load file or assembly 'myApp.XmlSerializers' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

MyApp uses a class that is derived from an ActiveX control. Everything works fine on the dev box, but on the test box I get this when I call CreateControl() on an instance of the class.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MyApp.XmlSerializers' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It seems that I am missing something on the test system, but I don't know what. I tried looking for 'XmlSerializers' in the Class and Object browsers, but I find nothing. I looked for a MyApp.XmlSerializers.dll on the working dev box, but there isn't one, so not finding it on the non-working test box isn't a surprise.

How do I chase this down?

Dave

Comment: That is a normal exception.  Press F5 to continue.  Or use Debug + Exception, untick the Thrown checkboxes.  Or use sgen.exe to pre-generate the serialization assemblies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FileNotFoundException in ApplicationSettingsBase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494886/filenotfoundexception-in-applicationsettingsbase)

Comment: Why is it not thrown on the dev box?  Also, the instance being CreateControl()ed, works as it should on the dev box but does not function after F5ing past the exception on the test box.

Comment: I used sgen.exe to pre-generate MyApp.XmlSerializers.dll in the same folder as MyApp.exe and the error remains.  Maybe the issue isn't the XmlSerializers file, but rather one of its dependencies.  I guess now that I have a persistent copy of MyApp.XmlSerializers.dll, I could use depends.exe to see.

Comment: Nope, nothing interesting in depends... there are some warnings about some WinRT delay-load dependencies (same on both the dev and test boxes) but nothing bad. Is there any way to tell exactly which file is missing when it says "Could not load file or assembly 'MyApp.XmlSerializers' or one of its dependencies."