# VS2019, C#, "just-my-code", and DLLs that aren't real

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I'm using VS 2019, a C# ASP.NET core 3.1 WEB API.

For reasons (I'll explain if anyone needs them), VS asked me to turn "Just My Code" off. A few hours later, in a different project, I got an `System.IO.FileNotFound` exception. The problem was a DLL didn't exist. The problem is, that DLL literally doesn't exist, it's not supposed to exist, and it will never exist.

After turning off Just My Code, I was working on a different project, Project-A (WEB API). It has a project reference to Project-B (Class Library). Project-B uses a NuGet package (Package-C). I wrote all 3 of these things.

I trigger an endpoint call to Project-A, the controller calls to Project-B, and when B tries to call a method in Package-C, I get a `System.IO.FileNotFound` exception. It's looking for `Package-C.XmlSerializers.dll`. But that's not a real thing. As I said, I wrote Package-C, and that DLL just ... isn't a real thing.

If I turn on "Just My Code" the problem goes away. We have not deployed this code yet, and I'm worried that it won't work on the server. And if it doesn't I don't know how I'm going to provide an imaginary DLL.

- Why is .NET looking for a DLL that doesn't exist and isn't supposed to exist?
- Why is Just My Code triggering this behavior? (I'm not 100% sure what Just My Code does, just a few bits I gleaned before writing this post.)

Some things that may or may not matter:

- I'm running Project-A et al in Debug mode, locally, using IIS Express, and CORS (requests coming from an Angular app being served from VS Code).
- I recently updated Projects A & B to .net core 3.1, because a co-worker recently updated Package-C to 3.1 (and added some functionality), and I needed the new functionality.
- Package-C *does* do XML Deserializing using `System.Xml.Serialization`; it reads XML from an old SOAP endpoint and deserializes it into a model.
- I have the out-of-date source code for Package-C on my hard drive (I haven't pulled co-worker's changes yet).

Thank you!

Comment: You are not supposed to see this exception, but might when you tinkered with Debug > Windows > Exception Settings.  Best to tinker it back.  Duplicate [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3798614/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant - thank you, you are right. Not sure what I did to Exception Settings, but at least the mystery of What Is Happening has been solved. Thanks! If you post this an an answer I'll mark it.