# Xamarin iOS app failing to run on device from Visual Studio

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2013

I have a Xamarin iOS app.  I have successfully paired my PC with my mac via the Xamarin Build Host.  iOS simulator build and run works great.  But when I try to run on my iOS device, I see a bunch of errors complaining about inability to find the PDB file, followed by the output shown below, and the app does not get installed on the device, let alone run.

Is it possible to run it?

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0x488 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1de0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1db4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'GraCalcIOS.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: GraCalcIOS.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\William\Desktop\Calculator\GraCalc\GraCalc.IOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\GraCalcIOS.exe'.  
Symbols loaded.
Remote build finished...
Debugging session ended.
Debugging session ended.
The program '[1828] GraCalcIOS.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: That might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516973. Other than that I'm not sure what can go wrong there is nothing wrong in your debug output, it seems like the app closed properly.