# Strange error in Quartz: Quartz.XmlSerializers not found

Tags: c#, topshelf, quartz.net-2.0

I am getting the following error in Quartz.net

> The assembly with display name 'Quartz.XmlSerializers' failed to load
>   in the 'LoadFrom' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The
>   cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not
>   load file or assembly 'Quartz.XmlSerializers, Version=2.0.1.100,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

It's very odd since Quartz.XmlSerializers does not exist anywhere in any code I'm using.  It's not in the Quartz source code, my code, and none of my dependencies best I can tell.  It only occurs when I debug my project, but not when I download the Quartz 2.0.1 source code and run the server from there.

I am using topshelf as the service install library.

It occurs during deserialization on line 226 of XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.cs of the Quartz source.

```
// deserialize as object model
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(QuartzXmlConfiguration20));
```

Any clue to solving this would be helpful as I'm stumped by this error.

Comment: Did you add Common.Logging as reference ?

Comment: Yes, but not the common.logging.log4net or log4net since I'm not using that library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In applications that use XmlSerialization, you can get a first-chance exception in outside code when the application looks for a cached serialization assembly.  You can find more information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127431/xmlserializer-giving-filenotfoundexception-at-constructor).

Comment: I have the same error, I found this error is quite annoying.

Comment: What's killing me, is I'm only getting this error under one solution. I have a project template using Quartz and have created several new projects with it, but only get this error under one solution.