# Handling windows newline with XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Recently, I replaced XmlValidatingReader with XmlReader and use XmlReaderSettings to validate the xml with an xsd.

```
CustomData cd = null;
using (Stream xsdStream = new FileStream(m_DXsdFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
  XmlTextReader sr = new XmlTextReader(xsdStream);
  using (Stream xmlStream = new FileStream(m_DXmlFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
  {
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    settings.Schemas.Add(null, sr);
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream, settings);

    try
    {
      XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = CreateDefaultXmlSerializer(m_Type);
      cd = (CustomData)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

  ...
}

XML:
<Column Name="Content">
  <Data xsi:type="xsd:string"> * info info info
info info info
 info info info</Data>
  <Data xsi:type="xsd:string">/* This is a test */</Data>
</Column>
<Column Name="ErrorNr">
  <Data xsi:type="xsd:int">2</Data>
  <Data xsi:type="xsd:int">2</Data>
  <Data xsi:type="xsd:int">2</Data>
</Column>
```

*CreateDefaultXmlSerializer() is implemented as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9416860/2107510*

However, XmlReader normalizes all newlines and converts \r\n to \n. This is not appreciated by the multi line text boxes which now display one line instead of multiple lines.

I tried using XmlWriterSettings.NewLineHandling.Entitize and it fixes my problem but this make the XML document no longer readable in e.g. wordpad or any other text editor. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinehandling.aspx)

**How can I preserve the multi line strings without losing them due to normalization?** (and without other nasty side effects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Creating Xml Readers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9khb6435.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> If you must expand entities on request (readers created by the Create method expand all entities), or if you **do not want your text content normalized**, use the `XmlTextReader` class.

Comment: XmlTextReader does not support XSD schemas (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfz3cz6w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Most solutions I find use XMLReader.