# Getting a system.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, exception

I am getting `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` and I am not sure why. It looks

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Pixelation Tool.XmlSerializers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

```
public static T LoadFromFile<T>(string name) where T : IName
{
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    (new FileInfo(filePath + name + ".mox")).Directory.Create();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath + name + ".mox", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    try
    {
        return (T)xml.Deserialize(fs);
    }     
    finally
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

it is calling it at the 1st line :

```
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
```

Comment: Well, did you check to see if there is a file named `Pixelation Tool.XmlSerializers` in your references or deployed directory?

Comment: You are probably missing a reference, or missing a package. Check your nuget dependencies and your project references.

Comment: Igar it is there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XmlSerializer giving FileNotFoundException at constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127431/xmlserializer-giving-filenotfoundexception-at-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a simple misunderstood made by visual studio intellisense “add using” helper.

Try to specify the full namespace, just like this:

```
System.Xml.XmlSerializer xml = new System.Xml.XmlSerializer(typeof(T))
```

and eventually remove references and usings to `Pixelation Tools`

Comment: it does not know what System.Xml.XmlSerializer is... I am getting an error

Comment: Ok, you need to add a reference to System.Xml assembly, so: in the solution explorer right click on the project, then Add->Add reference, then scroll down to System.Xml and select it, then click OK