# Why does XmlSerializer NOT cause FileNotFoundException in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer

So I originally encountered the issue described in this question: [XmlSerializer giving FileNotFoundException at constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127431/xmlserializer-giving-filenotfoundexception-at-constructor)

However, we just upgraded from Visual Studio (VS) 2013 Pro to VS 2019 Pro. Now, when I have all Common Language Runtime (CLR) Exceptions turned on (break when thrown) including System.IO.FileNotFoundException, I do not get a break on the exception. I thought it was something to do with the targeted .NET Framework (we also upgraded to .NET 4.8).

That said, I did a test:

1. Created a test WinForms project in VS 2019 targeting .NET 4.5.2, our starting framework version.
2. Add the following the default Form1 class:

```
public static readonly XmlSerializer kXMLSerializerList = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<string>));
```

3. Ensure all CLR Exceptions including System.IO.FileNotFoundException were on.
4. Build.
5. Launch the debugger in VS 2019.

**Result**: No break on an exception

OK, let's try VS 2013

1. Start VS 2013
2. Open the same project.
3. Rebuild.
4. Launch the debugger in VS 2013.

**Result**: XmlSerializer FileNotFoundException

So it doesn't seem to be a .NET Framework version dependency. An IDE dependency? That confuses me. Or is it a C# version dependency? Anyone have any clues?

Comment: In each version of VS, go into the project's build settings, click on advanced, and see what version of the language each is using.  They are probably using a different version of the language.  I think by default they're set to "Use Latest", but *latest* might be different for VS2013 vs VS2019.

Comment: Just to be sure: is this issue about vs _not breaking_ at the exception or the exception _not being thrown_?

Comment: @Amy: In VS 2013, Language version in VS 2013 is "default" and in VS 2019 is "Automatically selected based on framework version" with the control disabled. According to the[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) under the control, VS 2019's compiler is C# 7.3 for all .NET Framework version.

Comment: @RenéVogt, not being thrown based on the assumption: it is not breaking because it is not being thrown. I believe I have exception breaking set up correctly.

Comment: So it seems to be a C# 5.0 (if I change default to C# 5.0 in VS 2013, I still get the exception) vs C# 7.3 difference.

Comment: hopefully they removed this in the newer version. be glad that it is no longer thrown unnecessarily, why do you care?

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface. Don't get me wrong, I am very glad! It was annoying toggling CLR Exceptions on and off to avoid stepping through all of them. I may have a little OCD :). Just trying to learn more the compiler, IDE, and framework.

Comment: start looking here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/Compilation.cs,228

Comment: Maybe  you have different settings for "Just My Code" in VS 2013 and 2019 or the framework source code is available for the older version, but not the newer one.

Comment: @NineBerry, you were right. Updated answer...this is embarrassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bah. It was that "Just My Code" was checked.

I was thinking I had that unchecked, but I was wrong...sorry to all...

*Hangs head in shame* :(

Comment: In my personal experience, 99% of the time an issue with code stems from the language version and/or the framework version, usually the former.  It's almost never VS itself.  While the code you found might not be different between versions, the parameters passed in might be.  I have no idea how one would check that though.