# .NET 8.0 WPF Application fails trying to new a StringCollection()

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0

I am building a WPF application targeting .NET 8.0. In the System Settings on of the types that can be chosen is a System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection. I try to initialze the value in the Properties.Setting.Default by newinmg a StringCollection. It always results in this error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Specialized.XmlSerializers, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

I know of no place that I am using Xml Serialization! And have added this to my project file:

```
<GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
```

Anyone know how to get around this problem?

Comment: Well, the settings are stored as XML on disk, so presumably that's where XML serialisation is used.

Comment: Yes they are and the other settings store just fine. It is just the StringCollection that is giving me fits.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work fine if you ignore it? Based on my search, this may be normal behaviour.

An exception is thrown but handled by the XmlSerializer, so if you just ignore it everything should continue on fine.

You could avoid getting Exception popups all the time while debugging if you switch off first chance exceptions for that specific exception.

In Visual Studio, Press `Ctrl + Alt + E`, Common Language Runtime Exceptions -> System.IO -> System.IO.FileNotFoundException.

For more information you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1177040)

Comment: Thank you for the information. That's a good question, dumb as it sounds, I did not try that.

Answer (score 0):

What I have found out the problem was that I was using the system.properties accessible from in VS. Turns out that is not doable in .net like it was in .net framework. So, I ended up writing a simple class to keep a json file. That works quite well.